# Reactjs, onclick function is auto trigger

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning Reactjs. Let say I have a button, and on this button I trigger an event. But somehow this event always call event I don't click anything. Below is my code can you help me? Let say I call a api using Ajax, when having data I update UI. In UI I have a button and It also trigger an event.

```
"use strict";

var Movie = React.createClass({
    displayName: "Movie",

    getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
        return {
            movie_sessions: this.props.movie_session,
            movie: this.props.movie,
            rooms: this.props.rooms
        };
    },

    render: function render() {
        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            { style: column },
            React.createElement(
                "a",
                null,
                this.state.movie.name
            ),
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                { style: slide },
                React.createElement(
                    "ul",
                    null,
                    this.state.movie_sessions.map(function (movie_session) {
                        return React.createElement(MovieSession, {
                            key: movie_session.id,
                            room_id: movie_session.room_id,
                            date_time: movie_session.date_time
                        });
                    })
                )
            ),
            React.createElement(
                "div",
                { style: main },
                React.createElement(Seats, null)
            )
        );
    }
});

var MovieSession = React.createClass({
    displayName: "MovieSession",

    loadRoomFromServer: function loadRoomFromServer() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/rooms/" + this.state.room_id + ".json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({ room: data });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    loadSeatFromServer: function loadSeatFromServer() {
        console.log("click");
        $.ajax({
            url: "/seats.json",
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                //I want to update state for Seat
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function getInitialState() {
        return {
            key: this.props.key,
            room_id: this.props.room_id,
            date_time: this.props.date_time
        };
    },
    componentDidMount: function componentDidMount() {
        this.loadRoomFromServer();
        setInterval(this.loadRoomFromServer, 2000);
    },

    render: function render() {
        if (this.state.room) {
            return React.createElement(
                "div",
                null,
                React.createElement(
                    "li",
                    null,
                    this.state.room.name,
                    " "
                ),
                React.createElement(
                    "p",
                    null,
                    "  ",
                    this.state.date_time
                ),
                React.createElement(
                    "button",
                    {onclick: this.loadSeatFromServer()},
                    "Choose"
                )
            );
        } else {
            return React.createElement(
                "h3",
                null,
                "loading"
            );
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of calling the method, you should just assign the reference of the method in the onClick event

```
 React.createElement(
                "button",
                {onclick: this.loadSeatFromServer},  
                "Choose"
            )
```

Comment: If I use {onclick: this.loadSeatFromServer},  function is not call

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code. Event handler should be camelCase, e.g. `onClick` instead of lowercase `onclick`; And, as Phi Nguyen pointed out, you should pass the function itself, not the result of function call.

```
React.createElement(
    "button",
    {onClick: this.loadSeatFromServer},  
    "Choose"
)
```

In your original code, you execute `loadSeatFromServer` by calling `loadSeatFromServer()`, then assign the return value, `undefined` to a prop `onclick`, which is never used.

In the correct code, you do not execute `loadSeatFromServer` (no `()` after the function name), but assign the function itself to a standard event handler prop, `onClick` - and when the component is clicked, React will execute it.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution this is to bind the object you want like

```
self = this
```

...

```
onClick={self.coolFunction.bind(this)}
```

and

```
coolFunction() {
    console.log(this.someDataInside);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first change this :

`...
loadSeatFromServer: function loadSeatFromServer() {
        ...
    },
...`

to

`loadSeatFromServer: function() {
        ...
    },`

second :

`React.createElement(
                    "button",
                    {onclick: this.loadSeatFromServer()},
                    "Choose"
                )`

to

`React.createElement(
                    "button",
                    {onclick: this.loadSeatFromServer},
                    "Choose"
                )`